# Operator hierarchy in ++structure.field

Tags: c, increment, operator-precedence, associativity

The example:

```
++structure.field;
```

increments `field` instead of giving "wrong type argument to increment" compiler error, although ++ and . operators are equaly hierarchized ergo: should've been executed from left to right.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix and postfix `++` have different precedence. `.` has the higher precedence than the **prefix** increment operator, as seen on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

[image: Excerpt of the operator precedence and associativity table from cppreference.com]

`.` and **postfix** increment have the same precedence. If you wrote `structure.field++` then they'd have the same precedence and associativity would kick in to resolve the ambiguity as `(structure.field)++` rather than `structure.(field++)`.